# Number format in jQuery

Tags: jquery

What would be the conversion of this php function:

```
number_format('1486.10',2,',',' ') // return 1.486,10
```

to jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [this](http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format:481) implementation of `number_format`;

```
function number_format (number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
    // Strip all characters but numerical ones.
    number = (number + '').replace(/[^0-9+\-Ee.]/g, '');
    var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number,
        prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals),
        sep = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
        dec = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point,
        s = '',
        toFixedFix = function (n, prec) {
            var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
            return '' + Math.round(n * k) / k;
        };
    // Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
    s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n)).split('.');
    if (s[0].length > 3) {
        s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
    }
    if ((s[1] || '').length < prec) {
        s[1] = s[1] || '';
        s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0');
    }
    return s.join(dec);
}
```

Comment: I can see myself using this function quite a bit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [this](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/) jQuery plugin